# How to use comment documentation in GDscript?

Tags: godot

I trying to figure out how Godot documentation comments are working.
I apply them in my code, but I don't see any hints in a code editor, or in property-inspector.

Where it should be shown? How can I see these hints?

And related subquestion is there a way to document function parameters?

[Godot documentation comments](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_documentation_comments.html) :
"If an exported variable is documented, its description is used as a tooltip in the editor. This documentation can be generated as XML files by the editor."

But export keyword already in use, or do I get it wrong?
And there is no information about how to document function parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you are looking at is for Godot 4.0. Comment documentation is a Godot 4.0 feature, and does not work in Godot 3.x. I suspect you are using Godot 3.x given that you say:

> export keyword already in use

In Godot 4.0 export is no longer keyword. Instead, it is an [annotation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#annotations).

---

About documenting parameters, Godot does not generate per parameter documentation. *See the method descriptions for any class that Godot provides to see what I mean.*

Also `@desc` and `@tutorial` are the only supported tags in Godot 4.0 source at the time of writing. Instead explain to the parameters in the description. I believe the convention is to place the parameter name between `[code]` and `[/code]`. *To reiterate, this is a Godot 4.0 feature.*

Comment: vs code with godot-tools extension can show it tho.